# Do you need Excel for the Xceed DataGrid ExcelExporter?

Tags: c#, excel, xceed

In using the ExcelExporter in Xceed DataGrid, do we need to have a MS Office Excel installed in order for it to work? I am still planning on creating an application but the target PC does not have MS Office installed. But I would like to create a file that can be openned by MS Excel.

Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

No, you do not need Excel (or anything else) installed in order to use the ExcelExporter.